# Any easy way to create Login page in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, users, redirection

Most of the tuts I found want me to edit the `code` in `template` but I am not sure about editing the code, so, thought of asking is there any easy way to create Login Form in Drupal 7.

I don't want to show `login block` to everyone, and want to put it in some Page and visit it via `uri` like `http://localhost/login` then only the login page should show.

So, far I have made a `Page` called `login` gave it a `title` with empty `body`, Configured `user-login block` to be shown in `content` area and be displayed only in `login` page. So far so good, it looks cool, but the thing is: after logging in I can see the same login page as `Blank Page`. I did something like the `login page` would only be accessible by `anonymous users` but no luck.

My quest is either I should be able to `redirect` the users to main page after logging in, or have a separate `login page` instead of using the block which came by default with D7 installation. Any ideas ???

Comment: What's wrong with the standard login page shown at the path "/user" when you aren't logged in?

Comment: ha ha ha ha ha... you made me sound stupid, and yes I was, I was trying to create this all day long, and it was already there... god dammit me... Anyways, thanks a lot... BTW how do I change the `/user` uri to /`login`

Comment: You can use the path module to create an alias, BUT this particular path serves a dual function in that it's also where your user profile appears when you are logged in. So the effect may not be what you want.

Comment: Note, the path `/user/login` is also provided by default

Answer (score 2):

One easy possible way to do this is you can create a node with no content and assign a url "/login" to that node and then assign login block to content region for that page only.

Answer (score 0):

I entered the login as a menu-item but visible for all (just not as obtrusive as the login block). Just create a "Login" list item in your main menu (admin-interface: structure->menus->main menu->list links->add link) with path the (system) page "user/login". It will be visible for users who are not logged in, and disappear when they are.
If you also enter a similar (with same weight) list-item "Logout" with path "user/logout" that will only be visible for logged-in users, and now they can easily logout as well...

You can now remove the login block that is default on your homepage.

Comment: This might be a little complex for something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using either the [Luxe](http://dgo.to/luxe) or [LoginToboggan](http://dgo.to/logintoboggan) modules, as they do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

By default Drupal have a separate user login page. You can access it by using this url:

> http://yoursite.com/user/login OR http://yoursite.com/user

There is no need to create separate user login page.

To redirect the user to specific page after login, you can consider [LoginToboggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), [Login Destination](https://drupal.org/project/login_destination) or [Login Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/login_redirect) module.